# Virtualhosts, maintain existing applications

Tags: apache-2.2

I host several applications by IP in subfolders (http://ip/app). I would also now like to host a domain, I've been able to setup the virtual hosts so that the domain loads properly in it's document root however the rest of my applications stop working and point to the same virtual host document root of the domain.

How do I maintain my existing setup so all other requests behave the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the server's IP to serve the content separate from the new `VirtualHost` you configured.

The Apache server will default to the `DocumentRoot` specified outside of the `VirtualHost` when accessing the IP unless configured otherwise.  Specifying a `VirtualHost` with IP or a `_default_` VirtualHost would also work.

If you require additional assistance, please provide additional information including your Apache configuration file in full.

Answer (score 1):

If you had no VirtualHosts defined before, requests to the server will filter through the standard configuration in httpd.conf/apache2.conf.

This will mean that the hosts will bind to whatever's specified on the `Listen` line, and be served from the standard `DocumentRoot` specified in the Apache config file (by default this is /var/www/html on Redhat-based systems).

Once you start adding `VirtualHost` and `NameVirtualHost` directives, instead of following these conventions, requests to an unspecified `ServerName` will instead filter-through to the **first** specified `VirtualHost` stanza.

You can see this if you dump the Apache configuration with `httpd -S` (`apache2 -S` on debuntu):

```
[root@server]$ httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server somesite.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1050)
     port 80 namevhost somesite.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1050)
     port 80 namevhost othersite.org (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1074)
Syntax OK
```

You basically just need to define a VirtualHost which matches your default configuration, i.e set the `DocumentRoot` to whatever the main config `DocumentRoot` is, and configure the basic directives again so they're not overwritten. You **need** to place this VirtualHost as the *first* one in the Apache configuration.